# How to write state machines with c#?

Tags: c#, state-machine

I need to write state machines that run fast in c#.
I like the Windows Workflow Foundation library, but it's too slow and over crowded with features (i.e. heavy). I need something faster, ideally with a graphical utility to design the diagrams, and then spit out c# code.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ultimately, you probably want the newly redesigned [WF engine in .NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328), as it is much faster and provides a flowchart activity (not quite a state machine, but works for most scenarios) and a nice designer UI experience.  But since it's not yet released, that is probably not a good answer for now.

As an alternative, you could try [stateless](http://code.google.com/p/stateless/), a library specifically for creating state machine programs in .NET.  It doesn't appear to provide a UI, but looks well-suited to fulfill your other goals.

Comment: +1 for stateless.  It's a great little library and a breath of fresh air compared to Workflow Foundation (even WF 4.0).

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, Microsoft may have been ahead of their time with State Machine WF.  Sequential Workflows are being received much better.

When we decided on using a state machine, we rolled our own. because we couldn't find an acceptable framework with a UI.  Here are our steps.  Hope they'll help you.

1. Create your state interface:

   ```
   public interface IApplicationState
   {
       void ClickOnAddFindings();        
       void ClickOnViewReport();
       //And so forth
   }
   ```
2. Create the states and have them implement the interface:

   ```
   public class AddFindingsState : IApplicationState
   {
       frmMain _mForm;

       public AddFindingsState(frmMain mForm)
       {
           this._mForm = mForm;
       }

       public void ClickOnAddFindings()
       {            
       }

       public void ClickOnViewReport()
       {
           // Set the State
           _mForm.SetState(_mForm.GetViewTheReportState());
       }
   }
   ```
3. Instantiate the states in your main
   class.

   ```
   IApplicationState _addFindingsState;
   IApplicationState _viewTheReportState;
   _addFindingsState = new AddFindingsState(this);
   _viewTheReportState = new ViewTheReportState(this);
   ```
4. When the user does something requiring a change of state, call the methods to set the state:

   ```
   _state.ClickOnAFinding();
   ```

Of course, the actions will live in the particular instance of the IApplicationState.

Comment: Interesting implementation. Thanks for sharing.